# Jest spyOn vs mock - both defined and undefined errors

Tags: vue.js, jestjs

Just upgraded to jsdom-fourteen in my jest configuration. It's working wonderfully, but a single test is failing.

```
test('Do the thing', () => {
    window.location.assign = jest.fn();
});
```

I inherited this code. It looks like a simple enough jest mock. It complains that it cannot assign the read-only property `assign` and that makes sense, I assume this is jsdom functionality that was added.

However... I can't do a `jest.spyOn` either, which seems to be what is suggested. I've not used spyOn before.

```
jest.spyOn(window.location.assign);
```

But this gives me an undefined property error:

```
 Cannot spy the undefined property because it is not a function; undefined given instead
```

The line before this, I added a log just to check. It is definitely a function:

```
console.log(window.location.assign);
=> [Function: assign]
```

I'm not sure how these two errors can even coexist - both defined and undefined?

Comment: try to `delete` this property(`delete window.location.assign`) and then re-add it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually worked through some things and [found this](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/890#issuecomment-295939071):

```
delete global.window.location;
window.location = { assign : jest.fn()};
```

As it appears later iterations of jsdom lock the location object down further and further until it's completely not modifiable, @Estus' answer will only work in lower versions of jsdom/jest.

Comment: Notice that it's unsafe to do this outside beforeEach/afterEach because this results in test cross-contamination, `window.location =` assignment may also be a problem.

Comment: Gives me error `The operand of a 'delete' operator must be optional.`

Answer (score 3):

Due to how JavaScript works, it would be impossible to write `spyOn` function the way that allowed it to work like `spyOn(window.location.assign)`. Inside `spyOn`, it's possible to retrieve `window.location.assign` function that was provided as an argument but not `window.location` object and `assign` method name to do `window.location.assign = jest.fn()`.

The signature of [`spyOn`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object.html#jestspyonobject-methodname) is:

> jest.spyOn(object, methodName)

It should be:

```
jest.spyOn(window.location, 'assign');
```

This may be unworkable as well because `window.location.assign` is read-only in later JSDOM versions, which is used by Jest to emulate DOM in Node.js. The error confirms that this is the issue.

It may be possible to mock read-only property manually:

```
const origAssign = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(window.location, 'assign'); 

beforeEach(() => { 
  Object.defineProperty(window.location, 'assign', { value: jest.fn() })
});

afterEach(() => { 
  Object.defineProperty(window.location, 'assign', origAssign)
});
```

This wouldn't work with real DOM because built-ins may be read-only and non-configurable. This is the issue in Chrome. For testability reasons it may be beneficial to use `location.href` instead of `location.assign`.

Comment: `jest.spyOn(window.location, "assign");` gives me `TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'assign' of object '[object Location]'`

Comment: Yes, I was about to update the answer. This depends on which Jest and JSDOM (which is used by Jest to emulate DOM) versions are used. A lot of built-ins may be unmockable in real DOM, including `location.assign`. This is so in Chrome. You can try to mock it manually like described in the answer. But it's easier just to switch to location.href.